# Div Should Grow And Shrink with respect to screen size?

Tags: html, css

This code is for Carousal, the items are added to Carousal in Java script. When i re-size my screen, as i specified overflow = hidden my some part of image is not displayed or some part of image is hidden.

Html

```
<div class="line">
 <div class="s-12 l-6 margin-bottom"  style="position: inherit; margin: 3px; width:inherit; overflow: hidden;">
         <div id="owl_demo1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme  margin-bottom" runat="server">
         </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.owl-item
        {
            width:100%;
        }
      .carousol_image {
            /*height: 100%;*/
            height:450px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .item {
            position: relative;
        }

        .figure_margin {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        .titlebar {
            background: #333333;
            height: 80px;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
```

Java Script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#ctl00_ctl34_g_7a36e625_9f77_476b_aa4e_cc2258d2847d_ctl00_owl_demo1").owlCarousel({
         navigation: true,
         slideSpeed: 300,
         paginationSpeed: 400,
         autoPlay: true,
         singleItem: true
     });

     $(".owl-controls").css("width", $(".owl-item").width());

     $("suiteBar").hide;


 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries instead of just setting widths to 100%

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries